# should url for ajax get http request be url friendly for seo?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing, seo

The case:

Controller that get only get "GET HTTP" calls(WEBSERVICE) from website view or from android, iphone etc.. should have  url friendly url for seo?

(
user friendly url: `mydomain/param1/value1/param2/value2..`

not user friendly url: `mydomain?param1=value1&param2=value2..`
)

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 1):

SEO is irrelevant when it comes to webservices, it's not like you want your web service to be indexed by search engines. However, readability is *always* a good idea.

If you are looking for a consitent way to design a backend API that is readable and makes sense to end users, you probably want to do it in a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) way.

Comment: thanks,i know what you write, but i dont know if google search engine  works in that case - please give some latest reference for your opinion

Comment: @Yosef "*I don't know if google search engine works in that case*" - I didn't mention anything about *how* google works, I pointed out that in most cases you wouldn't be expecting users to be "searching" for your API via search engines. This is usually something you would document on your site for developers e.g. google have a section for [developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) which is all about how to use their API, however, their actual API isn't discoverable using search engines.